# Stop the loop with the "u" button

Tags: python, while-loop

I wrote a program that after pressing the "p" button, it starts to click by itself. but I don't know how to stop clicking. Who will do that to the "u" button?

```
import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

mouse = Controller()


while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        while 1: #The loop I want to stop after pressing the "u" button
            time.sleep(1)
            mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
```

Comment: The condition: `True` or `1` in this case must evaluate to `False`. Unfortunately these values never evaluate to `False` in Python. You need to either change the conditions or introduce `break`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of googling on `win32api.GetKeyState` (which does NOT give a nice neat boolean but rather gives this tricky int value that you have to do bitwise operations on to get anything useful out of) I think you might want:

```
while True:
    if (win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) + 2**32) & 0xffffff00:
        pyautogui.click()
```

i.e. you want the loop to continue running no matter what, and to continuously `click()` if the left mouse button is down.

If the clicking is too fast, add a `time.sleep()` inside the loop so that it pauses some period of time in between iterations/clicks.

Re: your edits/comments, here's an autoclicker that works via the "p" and "u" keys as you describe:

```
import keyboard
import mouse

autoclick = []
keyboard.on_press_key("p", autoclick.append)
keyboard.on_press_key("u", lambda e: autoclick.clear())

def poll():
    if autoclick:
        mouse.click()
    keyboard.call_later(poll, delay=0.1)
poll()
```

Comment: You helped me a lot, I understand what you wrote, I just don't know where to paste it. Could you give me a ready-made code? I will be very grateful.

Comment: I think that's literally all of it.  I don't have the packages you're using so I can't actually test it.

Comment: Unfortunately, but I mean when the mouse button is pressed, I have to click with a given frequency (which I regulate by time.sleep (frequency)). The program they sent me simulates an extra mouse click.

Comment: Maybe you could describe what happens when you run the above code and how it's different from what you want to have happen.  The code you posted in your OP doesn't have a `time.sleep` in it so I'm not sure if you're even talking about the same problem any more.

Comment: I would like when the left mouse button is pressed, it will simulate clicks with a frequency of e.g. 10 cps (click per second), but if I release the left mouse button, the program will stop simulating clicks.

Comment: And what happens instead when you run the above code?

Comment: the program simulates 2 clicks. one from my mouse and one from the program

Comment: i mean smf like this:

Comment: Okay, there's some trickiness in that `win32api` function that wasn't reflected in your OP.  Updated my answer to include the appropriate bitmask magic.

Comment: FWIW I might suggest using the `mouse` module instead of this awkward `win32api` and `pyautogui` stuff.  https://github.com/boppreh/mouse  Looks like you could just do this entire thing as a simple `if mouse.is_pressed(): mouse.click()` inside a loop instead of having to import two different modules and do all the crazy binary math.

Comment: I actually played with the `mouse` module jut to see if it was that easy, and it seems the caveat is that by sending a `click` event the button "releases", which means it's no longer detected as pressed (even if the physical button is still being held down).  You might encounter similar issues with `pyautogui`.  Not sure what the solution is there, but if you could use a *different* button to trigger your autoclicker it'd be a lot easier.

Comment: Okay, I have already written a simple program that when you press the "p" button, it starts clicking at a rate of one click per second. But now I would like to be able to stop clicking by pressing the "u" button. I edited the post and you can see how it works. The code is complete and 100% working. If you help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, in theory it should work, but not the program skips `if keyboard.read_key () ==" u ":` which causes break immediately and the program clicks only once.

Comment: I have one more question where can I change it to the right mouse button?

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#mouse.click

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you with an example:

```
a=0
while True:
    a+=1
    if a>=10:
        break
```

The command break basically stops the while loop.

Another way you can stop a while loop is:

```
a=0
run=True
while run:
    a+=1
    if a>=10:
        run=False
```

Comment: You too helped me a lot, I understand what you wrote, I just don't know where to paste it. Could you give me a ready-made code? I will be very grateful.